# gsub seems to be replacing everything between the first and last character in of the pattern, rather than repeatedly replacing the pattern

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

In the code given below I want to replace all occurrences of `"<a url>"` with `"link"`, but `gsub` isn't recognizing the repeated occurrences:

```
stringx<- " word1 word1 word1 <a url> /n word word word <a url> word 
word word <a url> abcd"   
gsub('<{1}.* *>', "link", stringx )
```

Output: " word1 word1 word1 link abcd"

Desired output: " word1 word1 word1 link word word word link word word word link abcd"

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the `.*` between the `<>` is capturing `a url> /n word word word <a url` try changing to `.*?` to make it non-greedy.

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question if this works.